# Why is 'Share this Folder' disabled in Google Chrome Bookmark manager on OSX?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

All my bookmark folders are marked as private in Google Chrome Mac Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) on Yosemite.

I want to share one of my bookmark folders with my brother. How can I do this without resorting to a third-party product like Xmarks?

The blue 'Share this folder' button is either disabled or completely missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just went through figuring this out. This is what worked for me. You can't share existing folders. To share a folder it first has to be set as public, which, you can ONLY choose while you are CREATING a new folder, which is totally lame. Also, if the new folder you make is in your bookmarks bar, it won't give you the option to set it to public, which is also lame. So, you have to make a new folder, that isn't in the bookmarks bar, set it to public when you create it, then drag all your bookmarks you want to share into it. Considering this is an extension from google I would expect better backwards compatibility and am kind of dissapointed. Hopefully google corrects this, otherwise I suspect most users will just give up on shared bookmarks, thinking it is a feature that doesn't ever work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue! I found these two temp solutions:

1. Links

I exported my bookmark folders and opened them in Chrome, and this gave me a list of links, which was somewhat helpful.

2. Changed profile

Since I really wanted the styling and convenience of just sharing a link, so I decided to export the bookmarks again, then import them into a new user profile. That worked. I'll post an update when I figure out what privacy setting I changed to disable bookmark sharing

I hope this helps.